# How add tables MS Word wiht POI languaje

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need create a document word with Java.
And I ask, how  can I do it? How can create tables?

And how I create bullets to paragraphs?

Net not have more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right.It does not have more info on net because it is not smart enough.

The one alternative that I'm aware of is [iText](http://itextdocs.lowagie.com/tutorial/rtf/index.php), which can generate RTF documents, which MS Word (and every other similar application) can read. It includes full table support.

And, of course, iText can generate PDF also.

Comment: Thank, i use now iText.But are not really good, almost,all i need not do it well. Thanks again.